# Java RMI equivalent in Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, rmi

I need to port a Java Application which uses RMI to Cocoa Touch ( iPhone/iPod Touch ).

It's a small application, maybe 600 lines of code thanks to the RMI simplification. But I was wondering what are my options to replace the RMI code in the iPhone/iPod Touch platform.

Thanks!.

Comment: What functionality of RMI are you looking for? Do you want the method invocation or are you looking for the ability to connect to any arbitrary IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) if you need two iPhone applications to talk to each other locally.

Comment: That works when you are in the same network, but I don't think it can be used over the internet... correct ?

Comment: Correct, but it's possible that it might be added down the line. You could probably write something with the usual CFNetwork classes, or run an HTTP server on one phone, with a REST client on the other end, etc.

Comment: The GameKit P2P works on an ad-hoc bluetooth network formed between two or more physically proximate devices.